# The $\in$ relation versus the successor relation on the minimal inductive set

Tags: set-theory

In ZF, the relation $\in$ is a linear order on the minimal inductive set $\omega$.
That is, the elements of $\omega$ form a "line" $L_\in$, starting from $x_0=\varnothing$, followed by a set $x_1$ with $\varnothing \in x_1$, followed by a set $x_2$ with $x_1\in x_2$, $\ldots$.

On the other hand, according to the comments and answers [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1626849/proof-that-the-minimal-inductive-set-does-not-contain-any-more-elements-than), the successor relation $\sigma$ (with $\sigma(x)=x\cup\{x\}$) is not necessarily a linear order. Specifically, one cannot prove that $\omega$ consists of exactly the elements on the "line" $L_\sigma$ starting from $\varnothing$, followed by $\sigma(\varnothing)$, followed by $\sigma(\sigma(\varnothing))$, $\ldots$.
That is, in some models, there can be elements of $L_\in$ that are not in $L_\sigma$.

My question is about the predecessor of the first element $x$ of $L_\in$ that is not in $L_\sigma$.
Since $\varnothing$ is in both $L_\sigma$ and $L_\in$, we have
$x\ne\varnothing$.
Thus $x$ has a unique predecessor $\pi(x)$ in $\omega$. By $\sigma(\pi(x))=x$, $\pi(x)\in x$. Thus, $\pi(x)$ precedes $x$ in $L_\in$. Since $x$ is the first element of $L_\in$ that is not in $L_\sigma$, $\pi(x)$ is in $L_\sigma$. But this means that $x$ has to be in $L_\sigma$, too.

Where does the above reasoning go wrong? Please help. Thanks.

Comment: There is no first element of $L_{\in}$ that is not in $L_\sigma$.  I think in this model you can have $L_\sigma$ being the standard $\omega$ followed by a copy of elements structured like the integers, so all the nonstandard elements have a predecessor.  If you require all of PA a countable nonstandard model has to have the nonstandard elements a countable dense set of copies of the integers, so $\Bbb {Q \times Z}$

Comment: Now I see it. Thanks, Ross.